# How to call public static methods in Unit Test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Hi I have a simple method as following and need to know how I can call it in Unit Test in Visual Studio

```
 public class myClass
 {
     public static bool Test(string value, string regex)
     {
         if (Regex.IsMatch(value, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
             return true;

         return false;
     }
 }
```

here is what I have sofar

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void TestMethod_Test()
 {
     string value = "myValue";
     string regex = "&#@<>\s\\\$\(\)";

     PrivateType pt = new PrivateType(typeof(myClass));
     bool actualresult = (bool)pt.InvokeStatic("Test", new object[] { value, regex });
     bool expectedResult = false;
     Assert.AreEqual(actualresult, expectedResult);

 }
```

Comment: Is the class `public`?

Comment: no, its not, it like class myClass{

Comment: Why are you testing framework code?

Comment: for my project I need to add bunch of unit tests, its part of standard procedure

Comment: If `myClass` is internal then it's bad practice to unit test it. You are then testing volatile implementation, rather than publicly exposed, stable, functionality. If your "standard procedure" requires you to undertake this bad practice, then your procedure needs fixing.

Comment: The method is providing no value as it only wraps the call to Regex.IsMatch(). I would recommend to call Regex.IsMatch() directly.
Also, instead of testing private methods I recommend testing the behavior of your class through its public API. In other words: Test the behavior for a matching Regex and the behavior for a non matching Regex, not the Regex matching itself.

Comment: @ChrisM, that's an implementation detail, it may be that the implementation will differ in the future or it may provide a default setting for the Regex method.

Comment: @DavidArno, if the code is not meant to be re-used outside of the library and the library is not meant to be re-used outside of it's context, it may bring value to test the Internal code. If this were a `private` method, I'd wholeheartedly agree, but as part of simple style rules and intellectual property protection, marking things Internal (to your company), may not mean they're not being re-used or "company-public".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not want to be using reflection. Just call the method directly:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod_Test()
{
    string value = "myValue";
    string regex = "&#@<>\s\\\$\(\)";

    var result = ClassContainingTest.Test(value, regex); 
    Assert.AreEqual(false, result);
}
```

If `ClassContainingTest` isn't public, then it isn't sensible to be trying to unit test `Test`. Only test publicly accessible functionality.

Comment: I'd like to nuance that last statement: If `ClassContainingTest` is `private` or `internal` and the library under test is a reusable API or component, it doesn't make sense to test it. If your whole library is marked `Internal` and the code under test is not being re-used, it may make sense to write a test for it, as the only other code calling it may be an application boundary like UI or a service layer. Making this an integration test would not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

If both the method and the class are `public`, then you could simply call

```
myClass.Test(value, regex);
```

If `myClass` is `protected` you could do:

```
public myClassWrapper : myChild
{ 
    public static bool Test(string text, string regex)
    {
        return myClass.Test(text, regex);
    }
}
```

If `myClass` is `internal` or '`default`' (no visibility specified, which seems to be your case) you can make make the assembly that contains `myClass` friendly towards the test library by adding an `InternalsVisisbleTo` attribute to it:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("myClassLibrary")]
```

That way your test project should be able to just invoke the Test Method directly as if it were public.

If the class is not public or you cannot alter the definition of the class, consider finding a method that internally uses the method you want to test and use that to verify the behavior. (e.g. test that the method that uses the `Test` method works correctly, thereby you test that the `Test` method works correctly.

Comment: thanks for for your answerm where do I need to add [assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("myClassLibrary")]? above my testMethod?

Comment: In the AssemblyInfo.cs of the project that contains the class `myClass`. See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx#remarks